# AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP7.1

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I just set up an Elastic Beanstalk for a Laravel Application which is just before Launch.
But it wasn't possible to choose PHP7.1 over PHP7.0.

Is there any possibility to install PHP7.1 on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk [supports PHP 7.0](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html). It also supports [custom platforms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html) based on an AMI you create. Have a read of the documentation and ask a more focused question if you get stuck.

Comment: do you know any resources for custom ami's for php7.1?